# Play Games - find nearby players custom UI

Tags: java, android, google-play-games, real-time-multiplayer

I'm using play Games RealTimeMultiplayer API in my game. At the moment, I'm trying to find nearby players, so the player can invite them to the game.

That's can be done via getSelectOpponentsIntent(). However, it launches a default player selection UI. I want to make my own custom UI. But I can't find any API function which finds (and returns) nearby players.

How do I find nearby players (without launching the getSelectOpponentsIntent())?

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43463046/edit) the question to be on-topic: include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that duplicates the problem. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What do you don't understand on the question? I clearly stated the problem and a desired solution. I really don't know why are you posting this here.